# Publish to FTP Failed to copy file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to publish a WinForms application onto a VPS via FTP.

I get the following error for each file in the deployment.

```
    Error   40  Failed to copy file '\\webserver\AthenaData\Athena\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Athena_2_4_0_0\DevExpress.XtraWizard.v11.2.dll.deploy' to 'ftp://ftp.cityworksgroup.co.uk/install/Application Files/Athena_2_4_0_0/DevExpress.XtraWizard.v11.2.dll.deploy'. Unable to add 'Application Files/Athena_2_4_0_0/DevExpress.XtraWizard.v11.2.dll.deploy' to the Web site.  The system cannot find the path specified (550).       1   1   Athena
```

Publishing to a local share works fine. I can connect fine to the FTP details I have used in a separate FTP application and applied full permissions to the FTP account. The application is building fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set all folders and files that you want to access to '777' using the other ftp program? As this would enable Write, Read and Full permissions to those directories.